# бесплатный sitemap генератор

Tags: sitemap

Здравствуйте.

Можете подсказать сервисы генерации sitemap, которые не ограничивают количество генерируемых страниц, если у тебя нет платного тарифа?

Comment: На какой платформе сделан Ваш сайт? Полагаю, наиболее удобное решение из имеющихся — воспользоваться средствами конкретно для Вашей платформы. Аргумент — можно настроить автоматическую генерацию sitemap при каждой сборке сайта. я пользуюсь Pelican и бесплатным плагином для него **[Sitemap**](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/sitemap). На моих сайтах нет огромного числа страниц, но вроде бы непредвиденных неприятностей при их наличии произойти не должно. Спасибо.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск софта на нашем сайте -- оффтопик.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью бесплатных и безлимитных сервисов по генерации файлов sitemap нет. В Гугл ходил, искал долго, благотворительностью никто заниматься не хочет. Да, и по хорошему, генерация должна делаться не обходом сайта по ссылкам снаружи, а "изнутри", например скриптом берущим данные из базы данных. Так будет быстрее, точнее и менее ресурсозатратно, особенно для больших объемов.
Ну а если вариантов нет, то вместо онлайн-сервисов можно использовать собственный компьютер. Например, под MS Windows есть бесплатный [GSiteCrawler](http://gsitecrawler.com), установили, настроили, запустили, ждем пока он обойдет весь сайт. Вот готова карта сайта в xml, html, rss и т.д.. Бесплатно и без ограничений. Под Linux тоже есть варианты, можно в репозитариях поискать, или использовать универсальный варианты, например [sitemap-generator-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator-cli) для NodeJS, на Питоне тоже можно найти рабочие скрипты.